trying to change color of an SVG icon (responsive Menu) in WordPress Theme "Clean Portfolio"
I've tried everything to change the color of SVG Icon, within the theme Clean Portfolio.
So far nothing works! The button has the id: primary-menu-toggle, within this there is the Svg class: icon icon-bars, as I said, no change, also I've tried fill: white.
nothing- any ideas what to do next? Now the icon is bearly visible, because there is an inline style, with a dark grey color, can't find this style nowhere! Website, under construction!: http://frankporges.de

Hi. The filter solution from this answer will work. General CSS questions are here offopic, a more appropriate place for this type of question is the [so].

Are you using https://catchthemes.com/demo/clean-portfolio/ theme?
I just tried following CSS and it changed the color on demo site
.menu-toggle {
    color: #345789 !important;
}

